# Getting data off of an infinitely running background thread onto the main thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, kotlin, concurrency

I should start by saying that I'm still new to multithreading and concurrency in Java/Kotlin, so please bear with me.

I've got a thread that is for a camera preview, that is constantly updating the preview with the next frame data. When I want to capture a picture, I need to take a particular frame's data and use it on the main thread. I'm currently using a blocking queue to store frames as they come in, until one is needed for picture capture.

```
private val mStreamRunnable = Runnable {
        var buffer: ByteBuffer? = null
        while (mIsStreamRunning) {
            try {
                // Obtain the data set in blocking mode. If it cannot be obtained after waiting for 100ms, it will time out.
                val frameSet = mPipeline!!.waitForFrameSet(200) ?: continue
                // Get color flow data
                val colorFrame = frameSet.colorFrame
                buffer?.clear()
                if (null != colorFrame) {
                    // Initialize buffer
                    val dataSize = colorFrame.dataSize
                    if (null == buffer || buffer.capacity() != dataSize) {
                        buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(dataSize)
                    }
                    // Get data and render
                    colorFrame.getData(buffer)

                    val colorDstSize = colorFrame.width * colorFrame.height * 3
                    val frameCopy: FrameCopy = copyToFrameT(colorFrame)
                    frameCopy.data = ByteArray(colorDstSize)
                    mFrameSaveQueue.offer(frameCopy)



                    mColorView!!.update(
                        colorFrame.width,
                        colorFrame.height,
                        StreamType.COLOR,
                        colorFrame.format,
                        buffer,
                        1.0f)
                    // Release color data frame
                    colorFrame.close()
                }
                // Release FrameSet
                frameSet.close()

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
```

This is where my problem is, as I'm not sure how to get that data off of that thread to use in the main thread. I have a second thread running to take the data from that queue and post it into a LiveData value:

```
private val mPicSavingRunnable = Runnable {
        var frameT: FrameCopy? = null
        while (mIsPicSavingRunning) {
            try {
                frameImage.postValue(mFrameSaveQueue.poll(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        mFrameSaveQueue.clear()
    }
```

This LiveData updates fine within the thread, but doesn't update outside the thread. The frameImage value on the main thread is always null, I assume because the thread hasn't finished yet. Essentially what I am looking for here is a way to have a constantly updating value on a background thread, and be able to use it on my main thread on demand, while the background thread is still running.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use Kotlin's coroutines instead of a Java Runnable?